# Any 2D frameworks/engines for Swift similar to Libgdx?

Tags: ios

I'm an android app developer who uses Libgdx and Java to make games, one of my teachers recently told me he could get me a career in the industry if I learned the iOS side of things too. A refurbished mac is in the mail and I'm about to learn swift, I want to remake and publish one of my games from scratch on iOS as proof and I need to know of any frameworks/engines similar to Libgdx I could use.

Comment: SpriteKit is Apples "offical" 2D framework.  You can also work with the Unity engine as well. If you're really keen, Metal will get you down to the coal face

Comment: I advise you to learn SpriteKit. Best way to learn swift, xCode and game needed patterns. in future it will be easy to write iOS native applications.

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but I've been working on an open-source game engine that combines SpriteKit, SwiftUI, ECS (GameplayKit) and tries to make cross-platform iOS+macOS game development easier: https://github.com/InvadingOctopus/octopuskit